# How to tell XMLReader not to read empty Elements

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am parsing some older XML Data which does not contain self closing elements.

All the elements have end-elements as well

```
<my-element someValue="xyz"></my-element>
<!-- instead of <my-element someValue"xyz" /> -->
```

When I parse the file with XMLReader in C#, the reader does an extra .Read() for any "empty content" within start-tag and end-tag.

When I add the contest to a list, I always get the wanted content, and an empty content added to my list.

I could get over the problem by calling

```
reader.Skip();
```

manually in the end of my loop, but that's rather hacky if i would come across some data files which DO containt self closing tags.

How can I tell the reader to skip all empty elements?

### UPDATE:

It works if I put an

```
 if(reader.IsStartElement()){...
```

at the top of my

```
while(reader.Read()){ ...
```

Loop

Comment: I wouldn't think this is possible.  You can tell if an element is self-closing as `XmlReader.IsEmptyElement` will be `true`. I'd think with that you could work out what to do in your loop.

Comment: Just found a solution: I am checking it by reader.IsStartElement();

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents for making this reusable and hopefully transparent.

```
public class NoEmptyElementsXmlReader : XmlReaderWrapper
{
    public NoEmptyElementsXmlReader(XmlReader xmlReader)
        : base(xmlReader)
    { }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        bool success = base.Read();

        while (IsEmptyElement && success)
        {
            success = base.Read();
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
var reader = new NoEmptyElementsXmlReader(XmlReader.Create(stream));
```

The generic wrapper class:

```
public abstract class XmlReaderWrapper : XmlReader
{
    private readonly XmlReader _reader;

    protected XmlReaderWrapper(XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        _reader = xmlReader;
    }

    protected XmlReader InternalReader
    {
        get { return _reader; }
    }

    public override XmlNodeType NodeType
    {
        get { return _reader.NodeType; }
    }

    public override string LocalName
    {
        get { return _reader.LocalName; }
    }

    public override string NamespaceURI
    {
        get { return _reader.NamespaceURI; }
    }

    public override string Prefix
    {
        get { return _reader.Prefix; }
    }

    public override string Value
    {
        get { return _reader.Value; }
    }

    public override int Depth
    {
        get { return _reader.Depth; }
    }

    public override string BaseURI
    {
        get { return _reader.BaseURI; }
    }

    public override bool IsEmptyElement
    {
        get { return _reader.IsEmptyElement; }
    }

    public override int AttributeCount
    {
        get { return _reader.AttributeCount; }
    }

    public override bool EOF
    {
        get { return _reader.EOF; }
    }

    public override ReadState ReadState
    {
        get { return _reader.ReadState; }
    }

    public override XmlNameTable NameTable
    {
        get { return _reader.NameTable; }
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(string name)
    {
        return _reader.GetAttribute(name);
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        return _reader.GetAttribute(name, namespaceURI);
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetAttribute(i);
    }

    public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix)
    {
        return _reader.LookupNamespace(prefix);
    }

    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name)
    {
        return _reader.MoveToAttribute(name);
    }

    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name, string ns)
    {
        return _reader.MoveToAttribute(name, ns);
    }

    public override bool MoveToElement()
    {
        return _reader.MoveToElement();
    }

    public override bool MoveToFirstAttribute()
    {
        return _reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    }

    public override bool MoveToNextAttribute()
    {
        return _reader.MoveToNextAttribute();
    }

    public override bool ReadAttributeValue()
    {
        return _reader.ReadAttributeValue();
    }

    public override void ResolveEntity()
    {
        _reader.ResolveEntity();
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        return _reader.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reader.IsStartElement** to check if element is empty or not.

```
    while (reader.Read()) {

  if (reader.IsStartElement()) {
if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
  Console.WriteLine("<{0}/>", reader.Name);
else {
  Console.Write("<{0}> ", reader.Name);
  reader.Read(); // Read the start tag.
  if (reader.IsStartElement())  // Handle nested elements.
    Console.Write("\r\n<{0}>", reader.Name);
  Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());  //Read the text content of the element.
}
```

} 
}